# how to use in python gpgme advanced (low-level) functions to delete a key?

Tags: python, gnupg, gpgme

I want to delete a key from my keystore, but the main module (`gpg`) doesn't provide any function to do it (or I missed it). Just to revoke key UIDs and that's not what I want.

I found that the function `gpgme_op_delete_ext (gpgme_ctx_t ctx, const gpgme_key_t key, unsigned int flags)` is avaiable through the `gpg.gpgme` module. But I don't how to use it because the GPG context I have is from the main python module and not of the required "low-level" type the function takes. And so I guess is my key I get from the `get_key` function of my context.

So, how can I convert my `Context` object from the main module and the key I get from it to feed the `gpgme_op_delete_ext` function to delete the said key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the GPG `Context` object has a `wrapped` attribut which is the data type `gpgme_op_delete_ext` requires. And for the keys, the object returned by `get_key` is accepted by the function.

So I can call it like this for instance:

```
context = gpg.Context()
key = context.get_key(fingerprint)
gpgme_op_delete_ext(context.wrapped, key, GPGME_DELETE_FORCE)
```